# Flutter firebase: Active a widget when collection contains a data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, widget

How do I activate and deactivate a widget when a specific data is in a collection of database in flutter?

I want that when the 'Status' field in a collection == 'not verified' a gesture detector widget with the chile 'verify your account' should be shown in the UI. else nothing should be shown.

My code:

```dart
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  StreamBuilder(stream: users.doc(uid).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      String status = snapshot.data['Status'];
      if (status == 'Not Verified') {
        GestureDetector(
          child: const Text(
            'Verify your account',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        const AccountVerificationScreen()));
          },
        );
      } else
        SizedBox();

      
    }),
```

Can anyone help me to rewrite the code correctly?

Comment: You need to use `return` on the widgets you want to build. `return GestureDetector(...);`, `return SizedBox();` (the latter could be `SizedBox.shrink()`).

Comment: I did really get it. could u write the code please

Answer (score 1):

You are not `returning` the statements , Try adding `return` statements

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  StreamBuilder(stream: users.doc(uid).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      String status = snapshot.data['Status'];
      if (status == 'Not Verified') {
       return GestureDetector( //  return here
          child: const Text(
            'Verify your account',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        const AccountVerificationScreen()));
          },
        );
      } else
        return SizedBox(); //  return here

      
    }),
```

Comment: It works but not immediatley. An error screen comes to that particular part of the screen first and after some time(about 15 seconds) it changes to what I wanted. What's happening?